# Removing ASCII &laquo; OR &raquo; from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to remove either « or » from a string to leave the remainding text in javaScript.

Have tried this to no effect:

```
$('body').delegate('.SearchPagination > a', 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        txt = $this.text().toLowerCase(),
        txt = txt.replace(/&laquo;|&raquo;/g, ''),
        txt = $.trim(txt),
        page = '&page=';
        console.log(txt);
    if (txt === 'next' || txt === 'previous'){
        // get the current page value
        var active = $this.parent().find('.active').txt();
        if (txt === 'next'){
            // add one
            page += (active + 1);   
        } else if (txt === 'previous'){
            // subtract one
            page += (active - 1);
        }
    } else {
        // invoke search with the page number
        page += txt;
    }
    console.log(page);  
    //icisSite.icisSearch.search(page);
});
```

Comment: This works fine: `"&laquo;test&raquo;".replace(/&laquo;|&raquo;/g, '')`. Your regexp is not wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using &laquo; in the regex, try copy-pasting the left arrow character displayed in the browser - i.e. the « sign. I tried that and it was replaced correctly. 
So your regex should look like -

```
 txt = txt.replace(/«|»/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
txt = txt.replace('&laquo;','').replace('&raquo;', '');
```

But i don't think this is the point since your regexp is correct, so, just in case (you regulare expression seems correct to me) , are you shure that when you get the text the htmlentities are encoded in the first place?Maybe the page is in UTF-8 and the entities are not encoded but displayed withouth encoding

Comment: Hi.  I guess the page is encoded prior to me getting to it therefore the reason for it failing is that it is not matching either &laquo; OR &raquo; as both are being output as << and >> in the string.  A bit stumped as how to proceed.